# Can I use const with overloading operators in Rust?

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

In this code:

```
#![allow(dead_code)]
use std::ops::Add;
struct Foo(i32);

const X: i32 = 1;
const Y: i32 = X + X;
const A: Foo = Foo(1);
const B: Foo = A + A;

impl Add for Foo {
    type Output = Foo;
    fn add(self, rhs: Foo) -> Foo {
        Foo(self.0 + rhs.0)
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
error[E0015]: calls in constants are limited to struct and enum constructors
 --> src/main.rs:8:16
  |
8 | const B: Foo = A + A;
  |                ^^^^^
  |
note: a limited form of compile-time function evaluation is available on a nightly compiler via `const fn`
 --> src/main.rs:8:16
  |
8 | const B: Foo = A + A;
  |                ^^^^^
```

What is the best substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. Namely, the implementation of `add` could do literally *anything* that Rust can do, including panicking, printing output, reading files, allocating memory, etc.

You will need to construct your constant "by hand":

```
const B: Foo = Foo(2);
```

You could also utilize a [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) which would generate Rust code that you then can include back into your program.

---

As the error message says:

> note: a limited form of compile-time function evaluation is available on a nightly compiler via `const fn`

However, that won't help you here and now as trait methods cannot currently be made `const`, and I doubt that `Add::add` (or any other operator trait) will be marked `const` as that would be overly restrictive — preventing implementations of `Add` from using all the features listed above. I don't know how specialization / subtyping will work with const functions.

Comment: *I don't know how specialization / subtyping will work with const functions.* => That's the big question, isn't it? I have no idea how the team is planning to handle that, and without the ability to use common traits such as arithmetic in constant expressions... they're going to be rather pointless.

Comment: Could the constness of a trait method be parametrized?

Comment: @JoelCornett my understanding is that such a thing is _extremely experimental_ and goes by the name [_keyword generics_](https://github.com/rust-lang/keyword-generics-initiative).