# Can Rust constant expressions use traits like Default?

Tags: rust, constants, default

This code gives an error:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct A {
    b: Option<()>,
    c: Option<()>,
}

const a: A = A {
    b: None,
    ..Default::default()
};
```

```
error[E0015]: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
 --> src/lib.rs:9:7
  |
9 |     ..Default::default()
  |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In this small example it's not a big problem, but if I have a struct composed by multiple structs that implement the `Default` trait, not being able to use it becomes at minimum an inconvenience.

While I could write this, it wouldn't have the flexibility that `Default` provides:

```rust
impl A {
    const fn new(b: Option<()>) -> Self {
        A { b, c: None }
    }
}

const a: A = A::new(None);
```

Is there any way to avoid doing that?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=675bd2803f513245b85fefdb5fef43ac ? "But then I wouldn't have the flexibility that Default provides." what is it ?

Comment: @Stargateur Not having to type all the fields I don't need

Comment: that not specific to default like the second answer say (and like my example :p)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use traits in a constant context. This is still being discussed in [RFC #2632 — Calling methods on generic parameters of const fns](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2632).

See also:

- [Can I use const with overloading operators in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43984358/155423)

Comment: Outdated, I believe. See Frxstrem's answer above.

Answer (score 10):

The `..Default::default()` syntax is not restricted to `Default::default()`, so you can write a `const fn` default-like function and use that inside of a constant:

```
struct A {
    b: Option<()>,
    c: Option<()>,
}

impl A {
    const fn new() -> A {
        A {
            b: None,
            c: None,
        }
    }
}

impl Default for A {
    fn default() -> A {
        // implementing using new() instead of #[derive]
        // to avoid diverging implementations
        A::new()
    }
}

const a: A = A {
    b: None,
    ..A::new()
};
```

[Run in Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ce2d368bb12458262c0590ba55acca6b)

Comment: And you can also use `..DEFAULT_A` with `const DEFAULT_A: A = A { b: None, c: None };`, you don't even need a function.